# AppCompat theme for Leanback

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-tv, leanback

I opened my old Android TV app project and tried to update the dependencies. I then updated the appcompat libraries to 27.1.1. I opened the leanback fragments and Android Studio warned me the `BrowseFragment` is deprecated and I should use `BaseSupportFragment` instead. Same case for other leanback fragments. I then changed all the fragment to AppCompat version (except for `LeanbackSettingsFragment` as there was no AppCompat version provided) and then changed my Activities extend `AppCompatActivity`.

After I made these changes, I built the app but when I launched the app I saw this error in logcat:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.swiftzer.trainboard.dev/net.swiftzer.trainboard.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

The theme I used for the app and activities are all under `Theme.Leanback`. But I checked the theme is based on platform native theme.

Should I stick with the deprecated leanback fragment classes or the leanback library do provides AppCompat themes? The leanback library is like a half-baked one. I saw the leanback library do provides an AppCompat version of fragments last year but no sample projects was using them. Now they marked the fragment classes extended from `android.app.Fragment` as deprecated but they didn't provide proper way to migrate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't use **Theme.Leanback** for Activities extending **AppCompatActivity**. For using **support fragments** you can't extend the activity with **android.app.Activity** either. For using **support fragments** extend your activity with **android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity**.

Answer (score 7):

You are not allowed to use `AppCompat` theme for Android TV with `Leanback` library.
You should extend your `BaseActivity` of the `FragmentActivity` to benefit from the `Support` Components.